# Access Dynamic Values from another Class in Swift 2

Tags: swift, class, oop, variables, instance

Here is the simplest form of the problem:

```
class A {
    var q: Bool = false

    func setq() {
        q = true
        print("A: \(q)")
    }

    func getq() -> Bool {
        return self.q
    }
}

class B {
    init() {
        print("B: \(A().getq())")
    }
}

A().setq()
B()
```

I cannot access `q` where `q = true` because `A()` in `B()` is a new instance of `A()`.

Is there any way to access the first instance of `A()` within `B()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the way *you've* written the code, no. You would need to provide B with a way for you to *hand it* an A instance. For example, `init` might take an A parameter.

At the moment you can't even do that, because you don't, *yourself*, have an A instance. You create an A instance in the first line of your code (`A().setq()`), and you then just throw that instance away. (Indeed, I'm surprised that the compiler doesn't warn you about this.) So not only does B have no reference to an A instance, but *you* have no reference to an A instance.

Here's a possible corrective:

```
class B {
    init (theA:A) {
        print("B: \(theA.getq())")
    }
}

let anA = A()
anA.setq()
B(theA:anA)
```

That is the very essence of OOP. It's all about arranging things so that (1) you have instances, (2) these instances *live long enough* to be useful, and (3) one instance can *get a reference* to another instance to which it needs access. Look in the mirror every day and repeat to yourself ten times: "The *code* lives in the *class*, but the *action* is all about *instances*."

Comment: I would suggest that you read the first chapter of my online book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch01.html